# SQLite query for retrieving data in order by for string

Tags: mysql, sqlite

TableMain

```
Task_Id  Task       Time     Date         Repetition    Snooze_Time
1        Meeting    22:59    23-3-2020    2             7
2        Meeting 2  20:40    23-3-2020    1             5
```

I need result like this: Where the `Time` is least and `Date` = 23-3-2020
Note: `Time` is stored as String(as you can see it has (:)colon)
Result should contain only 1 row.(Suppose there is no same time in the table)

```
Task_Id  Task       Time     Date         Repetition    Snooze_Time
2        Meeting 2  20:40    23-3-2020    1             5
```

I want to know that is query exist to retrieve data order by or `Time` or not.
If possible tell me the query.
If not possible tell me what can I do?

Comment: What is the format of `Time`? `06:05` or `6:05` or even `6:5`?

Comment: it is of 6:5 format because I stored it as 'text` datatype. How can I store it as 06:05 format? I recreated table and give `time` datatype by (column_name time). But still is storing as 6:5. format

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from TableMain t
where t.date = '23-3-2020'
and not exists (
  select 1 from TableMain
  where date = t.date and time < t.time
)
```

or with `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.Task_Id, t.Task, t.Time, t.Date, t.Repetition, t.Snooze_Time
from (
  select *, row_number() over (order by time) rn
  from TableMain 
  where t.date = '23-3-2020'
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

or:

```
select * from TableMain
where date = '23-3-2020'
order by time
limit 1
```

Note that you should only use the format `YYYY-MM-DD` for your dates and `mm:hh:ss` for time, because this is the only format that you can safely work with in SQLite.

Comment: what do you mean by t.* ,t.date and t.time

Comment: `t` is the alias of the table TableMain.

Comment: Why not just use the simplest way with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Oops, I guess because I had already written the not exists query and then I saw the condition `date ='23-3-2020'`.

Comment: time is stored as string, but it is in format hh:mm. So, will the 3rd query work?

Comment: All the queries will work for this case if the time's format is: `hh:mm` meaning there are leading zeros like `05:03`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But want to ask one more thing. What is the use if I store dates like YYYY-MM-DD format. At final sqlite going to store it as string then what make the difference?

Comment: For example if you wanted the least date in the table, you could not get it with your current format. A format like `DD-MM-YYYY` is not comparable.

Comment: Consider `23-3-2020`. It is considered less than `3-3-2020` because it is a string.

Comment: : ) Ohhhhhhh Great. Thx for your knowledge and also for solving my problem.

Comment: Ya sure. I didn't tried yet but it will definitely work and i will tick then

Comment: the time is not of 04:05 format. And recreated table and give the `Time` column datatype `time` but it is still showing time as 4:5?

Comment: There is no data type `time`. Although you define it as such it is actually `TEXT`, just like the Date column. You must update all the values of time and date with the proper format.